# Jrockit Stacktrace

Tags: stack-trace, shortcut, jrockit, java-mission-control, jfr

I need to know how to export stack traces from JRockit or atleast expand all traces.

Open a jfr file in Oracle JRockit Mission Control
Go to Events Tab
Click on Stack Traces

Is there any way we can expand all the stack traces at once and explore the logs?
Or is there anyway we can export the trace?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can recall, there is no way to expand all the stacktraces in the GUI (if you don't use something AWTRobot or similar...)

There are two other ways to extract all stacktraces to a log,
either use the Parser API (not supported), or the Parser main class (not supported either)

Both of them are referenced in this blog post (which also deals with extracting stack traces): http://isuru-perera.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/flame-graphs-with-java-flight-recordings.html

It might be a bit different because it's dealing with Java Flight Recorder, but the first version of Java Flight Recorder is quite similar to JRockit Flight Recorder, so it might be worth a try.